# split accents in w3m

Tags: w3m

I am trying to use `w3m` to view html email (via `mutt`).  Currently, accented characters (represented as HTML entities in the source, using a console and console font that supports accents) are rendered as two separate characters, the unaccented letter and the accent.  Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: What encoding are you using in the terminal? Does w3m display accents correctly on web pages? Are accents displayed correctly if you use mutt and w3m in an X11 terminal?

Comment: I am using utf8.  The issue is independent of mutt and the terminal (tried with xterm and konsole); in fact w3m will correctly display accents if I directly write them in the HTML source (e.g. `<html><body>é</body></body>`), but fail if they are written as HTML entities (`&eacute;`).

Answer (score 2):

w3m has a configuration parameter `alt_entity`, which when set to 1 (true) will give this behavior even when your encoding is UTF-8.  That's stored in

```
${HOME}/.w3m/config
```

and could be set in various ways, including the options menu where you can see it described like this line:

```
Use ASCII equivalents to display entities          ( )YES  (*)NO
```

You can override the config file using a command-line option

```
-o alt_entity=0
```